# Shorter regex to split by 2 criteria with spaces outside

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, i have a string containing: `'2014-12 to 1251255, 123123'`, and I want to get `2014-12`, `1251255`, and `123123`. This one is correct:

```
> '2014-12 to 1251255, 123123'.split( /\s*,\s*|\s*to\s*/ );
[ '2014-12', '1251255', '123123' ]
```

But is there shorter `regex` than above?

Of course I've tried:

```
> '2014-12 to 1251255, 123123'.split( /\s*(,|to)\s*/ );
[ '2014-12', 'to', '1251255', ',', '123123' ]

> '2014-12 to 1251255, 123123'.split( /\s*,|to\s*/ );
[ '2014-12 ', '1251255', ' 123123' ]

> '2014-12 to 1251255, 123123'.split( /\s*[,|to]\s*/ );
[ '2014-12', '', '1251255', '123123' ]

> '2014-12 to 1251255, 123123'.split( /\s*[,|(to)]\s*/ );
[ '2014-12', '', '1251255', '123123' ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match one or more digits or hyphen using match function.

```
> '2014-12 to 1251255, 123123'.match(/[\d-]+/g)
[ '2014-12', '1251255', '123123' ]
```

OR

```
> '2014-12 to 1251255, 123123'.match(/\d+(?:-\d+)?/g)
[ '2014-12', '1251255', '123123' ]
```

Comment: what's the case for the second one?

Comment: `\d+` one or more digits and a `(?:-\d+)?` following optional (`-` + one or more digits)

Answer (score 1):

Just split on `[^\d-]+`. It's a negated class which matches anything except numbers and `-`

```
> '2014-12 to 1251255, 123123'.split(/[^\d-]+/)
['2014-12','1251255','123123']
```